# Get rid of jQuery code redundancy, that differs only with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

## Problem description

I want my website to show plots when I click my element.

The problem is - I have like 4 places and 3 intervals. Thats is 4*3 = 12 plots:

```
var places = ['place1','place2','place3','place4']
var interval = [1,2,3]
```

for every interval I have got a seperate array of arrays that holds samples for each place separately

```
samples1[]
samples2[]
samples3[]
```

`samples1[0]` means "list of `interval=1` samples for `place1`"

`samples1[1]` means "list of `interval=1` samples for `place2`" etc..

Plot itself looks like this:

```
<div id="plot-place1">
    <div class = interval-button id = "interval1">interval1</div>
    <div class = interval-button id = "interval2">interval2</div>
    <div class = interval-button id = "interval3">interval3</div>
    <div id = "place1"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</div>
```

Function that shows default plot for specified place looks like this:

```
/* Shows plot's container (div) for place1, interval=1 */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on('click', '.place1', function(){
        $('#plot-place1').fadeToggle('fast');
        showPlot(samples1[0], 'place1');
    });
});
```

Then I have a function that, after clicking an interval button, changes single plot to show specified interval:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#plot-place1').on('click', '#interval2', function(){
        showPlot(samples1[3], 'sypialnia');
    });
});
```

So for 12 plots I have 12 same functions, that change plot's interval and differ only with arguments.
I have also got 4 almost same functions to show plot for specified place.

**THIS LOOKS GROSS!** I want to get rid of that redundancy, but I am new to jQuery and I know, there should be something like java template functions, but I don't know where to start.

Hypotetical templates for this would be:

```
/* shows plot's container (div)*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on('click', <plot's_place-based_id> , function(){
        $(<plot_container_id>).fadeToggle('fast');
        showPlot(<array_of_samples>, <place>);
    });
});

/* shows specified plot */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(<plot_container_id>).on('click', <interval_button_id>, function(){
        showPlot(<array_of_samples>, <place>);
    });
});
```

## Questions

1. How to get rid of that redundancy?
2. Was it clear to understand the problem?
3. How screwed am I?

Comment: You can set plot_container_id as data attribute in the element you attach your events to and get it through event target element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ID's for repeating modules like this...use common classes.

You can also use data attributes or indexing to assist for things like which button was activated

Example with 2 repeating modules:

```js
var intervals = {
  'place1': [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ],
  'place2': [
    [11, 12, 13],
    [14, 15, 16],
    [17, 18, 19]
  ]
}

function showPlot($el, place, plotIndex) {
  // display place and interval array for demo
  $el.html(place + ' - ' + JSON.stringify(intervals[place][plotIndex]))
}

$('.interval-button').click(function() {
  // isolate place instance container based on `this`
  var $cont = $(this).closest('.plot-place'),
    place = $cont.data('place'),
    plotIndex = $cont.find('.interval-button').index(this),
    $plotEl = $cont.find('.place')
  showPlot($plotEl, place, plotIndex)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plot-place" data-place="place1">
  <h4>Place 1</h4>
  <button class="interval-button">interval1</button>
  <button class="interval-button">interval2</button>
  <button class="interval-button">interval3</button>
  <div class="place"></div>
</div>

<div class="plot-place" data-place="place2">
  <h4>Place 2</h4>
  <button class="interval-button">interval1</button>
  <button class="interval-button">interval2</button>
  <button class="interval-button">interval3</button>
  <div class="place">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
</div>
```